# In react-beautiful-dnd I conterminously get "Droppable: unsupported nested scroll container detected."

Tags: react-beautiful-dnd

Any idea why in react-beautiful-dnd I conterminously get "Droppable: unsupported nested scroll container detected." ?

```
react-beautiful-dndDroppable: unsupported nested scroll container detected. 
A Droppable can only have one scroll parent (which can be itself)Nested scroll containers are currently not supported.
```

Comment: Hello Dan, you should check the issue here: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/362#issuecomment-375528521

Adding ``{{overflow:auto}}`` to DragDropContext element nested in a div (or any other tag) should fix it.

Comment: If you're using Material UI, check this issue for my fix: https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/issues/362#issuecomment-712353246

Answer (score 0):

This error message is indicating that a Droppable component in a user interface has detected an unsupported nested scroll container. A Droppable component is used for creating a drop target in a drag-and-drop interface, and it can only have one scroll parent. The error message is saying that there are multiple nested scroll containers, which is currently not supported.

I made the same mistake,
To fix this check your overflow CSS properties and **avoid nested scroll conditions**

Answer (score 0):

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION to 'NESTED SCROLLING CONTAINER DETECTED' error**
This fix only applies if Overflow-X or Overflow-Y is being set on any parent container of the Droppable container

A fellow react developer and myself just spent several hours trying to solve this one.
Here is what we discovered.

**OUR SETUP**
We are using 'react-beautiful-dnd' with a 'react-virtualized' list, and using 'ant-design' as our UI Library.

**WHAT TRIGGERS THE ERROR:**
==> IF a parent to the Droppable container has Overflow-X or Overflow-Y set to (hidden or auto), without also setting the other 'X' or 'Y' to hidden. THEN react 'assumes on its own' and auto-sets the one you DID NOT SET, (either Overflow-Y or Overflow-X) to 'auto' ...triggering the error.

It is automatically setting the one you did not set, to 'auto', turning the parent into a 'Scrolling Container'.

**TO FIX THIS:**

- In our case, we removed the Overflow-X (hidden or auto) style from the parent container, and replaced it with (Overflow: 'hidden'). You could also just ensure that NO OVERFLOW setting is set, or set BOTH overflow X & Y to 'hidden'.
- Just DO NOT set one without the other!